# Open a windows form from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml, mvvm

I am working on a legacy product, in which everything until now was made using windows forms. Due to requirements involving high usage of XMLs, I using WPF due to its ease of binding. I am using the MVVM model since the requirement requires different views but not much difference in the business logic. **I have an user control, which has a button to open up a windows form. And this user control is again on different windows forms.**

This is the code for my xaml related to the button:

```
<UserControl x:Name="ctrlTemplate" x:Class= "CtrlTemplate"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFControl.UI"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:xckt="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="{DynamicResource ViewModel}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
            <local:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

And here is the command binding with the button

```
<Button x:Name="btnOpenWindowsUI" Command="{Binding OpenWindowsUI, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}" CommandParameter={????} >
```

My ViewModel is like this:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand OpenWindowsUI{ get; set; }
    public OTCViewModel()
    {
        OpenWindowsUI= new OpenWindowsUI(this);
    }
}
```

And my command looks like this:

```
class OpenWindowsUI: ICommand
{
    private ViewModel _mvModel;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { }
        remove { }
    }
    public ClearAllData(ViewModel mvModel)
    {
        _mvModel = mvModel;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        IWindowsUI indowsUIInstance = null;
        windowsUIInstance = _container.Resolve<IWindowsUI >();
        frmWindowsUI = windowsUIInstance.Reference();
        frmWindowsUI.Owner = this; **//How can we specify the parent of this chid form?**
        frmWindowsUI.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        windowsUIInstance.SetUp();
        frmWindowsUI.Show();
        frmWindowsUI.FormClosed += frmWindowsUI_FormClosed;
    }
}
```

I know one can easily find the parent form from the usercontrol code using the following snippet:

```
public Form FindParentWindowsForm()
{
    var source = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromDependencyObject(btnOpenWindowsUI);
    Form form;
    if (source != null)
    {
        var host = (System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost)System.Windows.Forms.Control.FromChildHandle(source.Handle);
        if (host != null)
        {
             form = (Form)host.TopLevelControl;
        }
    }
    return form;
}
```

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to pass the UI element from control to ViewModel?
2. Should we pass reference of an UI element to ViewModel?
3. If not what is the best way to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you can.
2. No. You shouldn't pass a UI Element to a ViewModel in MVVM.
3. You can create a separate control and tie it to the view. Create some dependency property in the control. Change the value of the property through the ViewModel. As you can change the value, control gets the dependency property invoked which has now the visual tree of controls in the window.

Please refer http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#ConfirmationRequestor

Answer (score 1):

I don't have full solution for You however:

.1. Yes You can - For instance below code will pass whole Window object as CommandParameter:

```
    <button [...] CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

.2. This question is a topic to typical MVVM debate. On the one hand UIElement is just an object, which in high-level point of View is not really different than other objects like Properties, BUT on the other hand passing UIElement as parameter is kinda breaking MVVM since from this moment ViewModel will be aware of the View.

.3. Do You have access to element You want to pass inside Your User Control in any manner ?